# Can i customise react-three-fiber global render loop?

Tags: three.js, webgl, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I want to add delay to render loop, to reduce CPU load

In common threejs im able to do smth like this:

```
//.ts
    startTime = performance.now()
    ...
    requestAnimationFrame(function render(time: number) {
        if (time - this.startTime > 10) { // 10ms render delay
            this.renderer.render(...)
            this.startTime = performance.now()
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(render)
    })
```

But in react-three-fiber the only option i found is to set "render mode", like

```
//.tsx
<Canvas frameloop="<'always' | 'demand' | 'never'>" ></Canvas>
```

I need to do this to reduce battery heat. Also the 'demand' state is not for me, bc i need to always render the scene. Also i know about progressive dpr scaling and this is not what im looking for

I tried to look through the documentation and source code but didn't find a solution. Maybe someone had the same problem and succeeded?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should mess with milliseconds and all those time calculations because you might get random dropped frames at unexpected times. Instead, you should just cut your frames in half. Most framerates on people's devices is 60FPS. So you could drop this to 30FPS by only rendering every-other-frame:

```js
let skipFrame = false;

function render() {
    // Alternate between true/false
    skipFrame = !skipFrame;

    // Render if not skipping
    if (!skipFrame) {
        this.renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

Comment: Got u, good to know, nevertheless im still looking for a way to do smth like that in react-three-fiber

Comment: @DenKravchu oh, I think you need this then: https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/api/hooks#taking-over-the-render-loop

Comment: Its not exactly that, but the only way i understood how i can do this, is while using useFrame hook cut fps to separate part of code, but this is not so convenient. however thx for try